# Are preprocessor directives processed before macros are expanded?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Are preprocessor directives processed before macros are expanded ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Each preprocessor directive defnes its own interaction with macro replacement. The general rule is (C++11 16/6):

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise
>   stated.

Another relevant general rule is 16/1:

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the following constraints:
>   The first token in the sequence is a `#` preprocessing token that (at the start of translation phase 4) is either
>   the first character in the source file (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or that
>   follows white space containing at least one new-line character. The last token in the sequence is the first newline
>   character that follows the first token in the sequence. A new-line character ends the preprocessing
>   directive even if it occurs within what would otherwise be an invocation of a function-like macro.

(Translation phase 4 is preprocessing).

Some rules for individual directives:

- `#if` and `#elif` expand macros in their arguments, except for arguments of `defined` (16.1/4).
- `#include` expands macros in its arguments; they must eventually expand to a string delimited by `""` or `<>`.
- `#line` expands macros in its arguments; they must eventually expand to valid syntax for non-macro arguments to `#line` (16.4/5)